# Counting weakly connected graphs with outdegree of exactly one.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, connectedness

If we count all graphs of $N$ labelled vertices, where each vertex has an outdegree of exactly $1$ with no self-loops allowed, we'll find that there are exactly $(N-1)^N$ of them (for every of $N$ vertices we can choose one of out $N-1$ other verties to draw an arrow to).

Question is, how many of them are weakly connected?

The closest I got to a solution is looking in what way can the graph be **not** connected, and subtracting those from the total amount of graphs. As such, this yields the following formula:

$$F_N = (N-1)^N-\sum_{\lambda\vdash N,\lambda\ne[N]}\left(N!\prod_{i\times r\in\lambda}\frac{(F_i / i!)^r}{r!}\right)$$

$$F_1 = 0$$

Here, $\lambda\vdash N,\lambda\ne[N]$ means that $\lambda$ is a partition of $N$, but does not consist of $N$ alone. $i\times r\in\lambda$ means that $i$ occurs $r$ times in $\lambda$.

Is there a simpler formula? E.g non-recursive or one that doesn't require summing or multiplying over a "weird" set like partitions and occurences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a directed graph with no self-loops in which every vertex has out-degree $1$. Suppose that the vertex $v_0$ is a source (i.e., its in-degree is $0$). Then there is a unique directed path-with-cycle $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_k,v_\ell$ such that $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,k-1\}$. If no vertex of $G$ is a source, let $v_0$ be any vertex of $G$; then there is a unique directed cycle $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_k,v_0$. In either case, if the vertices of $G$ have not been exhausted, we can repeat the process. In this way we decompose $G$ into disjoint directed paths-with-cycles and cycles. There cannot be an edge between two of these pieces, because its the vertex at its tail would have out-degree at least $2$. Thus, if $G$ is weakly connected if and only if it has just one piece.

Suppose that $G$ has $n$ vertices. Either $G$ is a cycle, whose vertices can be labelled in $(n-1)!$ ways, or it’s a path-with-cycle of the form $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1},v_\ell$ for some $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,n-2\}$. In that case there are $n!$ ways to permute the vertex labels and $n-2$ choices for $\ell$, so there are $(n-2)n!$ labelled graphs of this type. The total is

$$(n-1)!+(n-2)n!=\big(1+n(n-2)\big)(n-1)!=(n-1)^2(n-1)!\;.$$

**Added:** This is an incomplete count: the paths from two sources can converge. It's time for bed; tomorrow I’ll either fix or delete it. With vertices $a,b,c$, and $d$, for example, you can have edges $\langle a,d\rangle,\langle b,d\rangle,\langle c,d\rangle$, and $\langle d,c\rangle$, and this graph is not counted above.

**Added<sub>2</sub>:** The original argument actually shows that $G$ must consist of a directed cycle with some non-negative number of directed paths feeding into it. Let $k\ge 2$ be the length of the cycle, and suppose that $k<n$. There are $\binom{n}k$ choices of labels for the cycle, and then $(k-1)!$ ways to permute them. There are $(n-k)!$ ways to permute the remaining vertices. For $1\le\ell\le n$ there are $\binom{n-k-1}{\ell-1}$ ways to split the list of remaining labels into $\ell$ non-empty segments, each of which will label a path from a source to the cycle, and then there are $k^\ell$ ways to choose where the paths enter the cycle. However, each set of $\ell$ segments is produced in this way from $\ell!$ permutations of the remaining $n-k$ labels, so the correct total is

$$\begin{align*}
(n-1)!&+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(k-1)!\binom{n}k\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-k}\frac{k^\ell}{\ell!}(n-k)!\binom{n-k-1}{\ell-1}\\
&=(n-1)!+n!\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-k-1}\frac{k^\ell}{(\ell+1)!}\binom{n-k-1}{\ell}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: But there are 78 such graphs of 4 vertices, and $(4-1)^2(4-1)! = 54$

Comment: @mniip: Can you exhibit one that isn’t of either of the two forms that I discussed? Never mind: I see what I missed.